# Tableau Embed from Tableau Public not auto-resizing in iFrame

Tags: tableau-api, iframe-resizer

I'm in the process of working with an org to build a website that will display tableau embeds from Tableau Public, but I am running into a problem with how the tableau is displaying. I have tried following some of the resources available on Tableau's website, such as making sure the dashboard is set to automatically resize, etc....

The website is a wordpress website, and it is written so whenever a tableau embed code from Tableau Public is detected, it automatically puts it into an iFrame. From Tableau Public, I am using the longer of the two embed codes available.

I have made sure the dashboard to the tableau is set to "automatic" sizing so it should auto-adjust to the screen. This doesn't seem to work and the tableau embed is too large.

One of the things I found in the resource guide on tableau is if your website starts with !doctype html then to use the following code in the embed:

```
<style> html, body{height:100%} </style>
```

Should I place this in the embed code or it wouldn't matter since it's being placed in an iFrame? If I should use it, where in the code should it go?

The iFrame code on the website that the tableau is placed in is:

```
.tableauPlaceholder{

height:auto !important;

padding-bottom:60%;

overflow:hidden;

}



.tableauPlaceholder iframe{

height: 100% !important;

width: 100%;

position:absolute;

}
```

The idea is that whenever I or another user embeds the Tableau code, the code above automatically detects the embed and places it inside this iFrame.

should something with the above code be changed?

I expect the tableau to fit correctly on the screen in-which it is being displayed. The user shouldn't have to zoom out or scroll to see/interact with the graph.

Thanks for your help, I'd be more than glad to clarify anything above/provide more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the dashboard is created with **Automatic** in Tableau, then the display using Embed or API will scale appropriately in your web pages.

Else,
In the embed code you may find a code like this:

```
if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { 
    vizElement.style.width='850px';
    vizElement.style.height='1727px';
  }
else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { 
    vizElement.style.width='850px';
    vizElement.style.height='1727px';} 
else { 
    vizElement.style.width='100%';
    vizElement.style.height='2077px';}
```

You can adjust dimensions according in the embed code itself.